# Animation using Javascript or link CSS to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

could any kind soul help me in my program as I am new to HTML, Javascript, and CSS? In my CSS, I have 4 different animations going to different locations. So for example if, I want to do a case structure, for example, press A for robot A, press B for robot B, so on so fore.

Below will be the program for my CSS part. Hopefully, someone will be able to help me. Or is there anyway, I'm able to link my CSS to javascript?

```
<style>

#robot {
  position: fixed;
  top: 280px;
  left: 600px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name:robot;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  #robot2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 180px;
    left: 500px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name:robot2;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    #robot3 {
      position: fixed;
      top: 180px;
      left: 400px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 50px;
      height: 60px;
      -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
      -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
      animation-name:robot3;
      animation-duration: 5s;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      }
      #robot4 {
        position: fixed;
        top: 180px;
        left: 300px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 50px;
        height: 60px;
        -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
        -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
        animation-name:robot4;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('TPHRG floorplan1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* background-position: center; */
  background-size: 980px 400px, cover;
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */

 @-webkit-keyframes robot {
 0%  {top: 280px;left:600px;}
 50% {top: 180px;left:600px;}
 100% {top: 180px;left:500px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes robot2 {
from {top: 180px;left:500px;}
to {top: 180px;left:400px;}

}
@-webkit-keyframes robot3 {
from {top: 180px;left:400px;}
to {top: 180px;left:300px;}

}
@-webkit-keyframes robot4 {
from {top: 180px;left:300px;}
to {top: 180px;left:200px;}

}


</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess currently your animations run automatically. To make them work on some event use `transition`.

Here is the working code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .robot_start_left {
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
        left: 0px;
        transition: left 1s;
      }

      .robot_start_top {
        top: 0px;
        transition: top 1s;
      }

      .robot_end_top {
        top: 100px;
      }

      .robot_end_left {
        left: 100px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body onkeydown = 'move(event)'>
 <div class="robot_start_left robot_start_top" id="app"></div>  
  <script>
    var move = function (event) {
      if(event.keyCode === 65) {
        const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
        appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left")
      }

      if(event.keyCode === 66) {
        const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
        appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top")
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED**

Press A to move the robot left -> right.

Press B to move the robot top -> bottom

Have a great day !!

Comment: Thank for your reply, but if I want to do something like moving down and to the right, what should I need to do ?

Comment: Add transition for `Top` and `bottom` property, and add separate classes for them

Comment: Thank for the reply once again. Another question is, how do I add my own photo inside? Not to the background but just a normal image.

Comment: use `<img>`. and add the same classes

Comment: Thank you for the update, Why is it when I press on A it straight jumps to the right and when I pressed on B it will move down normally.

Comment: It's because we are using two transitions at once. So you should add them as per your  requirement and remove them dynamically using JS

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand how to do it. Could you please elaborate more. Thanks